# Get MP3 File Duration in Windows Phone 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mp3, mediaelement

How can I get media element source (mp3 file) duration in windows phone 8 without playing the file.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways of doing this I can think of at the moment, however I´d recommend you to do it in this way:

- first is to read it directly from file's MusicProperties by using [GetMusicPropertiesAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.getmusicpropertiesasync):

[image]

You might need to adapt the code a little bit, tell me if there´s something else you do need.

Comment: Please note that the file is an online link. ex: http://file.mp3. So, how can I use: var audioFile = await mp3FilesFolder.GetFileAsync("sound.mp3"); and what is mp3FilesFolder?

Comment: @SamarElFwakhry, I don´t understand, what do you mean with online link?

Comment: In that case you have to download the file first into your device, then you can set a variable that gets the name of the file `Path.GetFileName`, and then you replace in my code the `sound.mp3` with that variable name. I would suggest to read a bit before asking. You did not post any question at alll, just a goal.

Comment: But what if I have a lot of files (with large size) I don't need to download all of them?

Comment: I´m not sure right now, but I think that where I wrote `sound.mp3` you can replace with the link that you posted. Let me know if it works, cuz now I am not at home so I can´t check if it does.

Comment: What is mp3FilesFolder?